# How to Save an Array Index and Value at Separate Col With Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, controller

Sorry if My English is Bad.

I Have Table Just like this,Only Two Col :

> Meta-col , Value-col

Now I Get My Inputs at Array Like This:

```
$settings=$request->all();
```

So My Result is something like This :

```
{
"_method": "PATCH",
"_token": "Yk3l3GsacKV6plkXH0zNKLVL2HcYjZbg2kB8KeAp",
"site_title": test,
"blog_description": blog test,
"admin_email": admin@gmail.com,
"site_language": "eng",
...
}
```

Well,I Want Save Index in Meta-col & Values in Value-col.

My Table Should be Like This :

```
Meta-col           Value-col
 ----------        ----------
 site_title          value 
 blog_description  blog test
  .......           ....
```

I try This Codes But Not Working and Get Error :

```
$settings->save();
```

or

```
 foreach ($metas as $meta =>$value){
       echo "<p style='color:red;text-align: center'>". $meta ."</p>";
       echo "<p style='color:blue;text-align: center'>". $value ."</p>";
 }
```

Well,With This `Foreach` I can Get Each Meta & Value separate But Still I Don't Know How To Manage it.

And Also Tested Some other Code's But Still Not Work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a Model for your table in database you can do :

*Say your Model is MyModel*

```
foreach ($metas as $meta =>$value){
        $m = new MyModel();
        $m->Meta_col = $meta;
        $m->Value_col = $value;
        $m->save();
 }
```

In order for your variable to be `save()`d to the database it has to be of type

`class MyModel extends Model {}` where `Model` being `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`.

I didn't catch your laravel version so [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#introduction) is a starter from the last version.

Comment: yes.It Work's. Thanks Buddy. My  laravel version is 5.6

Comment: Np. Glad to help